# Don't work "Enter" button as I want

Tags: java, comments

I tried to look on your website hot to make posts with adding 
 while using "Enter" button.

I had

```
sendDataComment.comment = commentForm.find("textarea").val();
```

I added

```
sendDataComment.comment = commentForm.find("textarea").val().replace(/\\n/g, "<br />");
```

But I still have "hi! how are you?" in one line in my post, although I in phpmyadmin it in two lines

```
hi!
how are you?
```

How can I fix that problem and keep 
 in my post?

Answer (score 0):

I would like to update my question.

with

```
sendDataComment.comment = commentForm.find("textarea").val().replace(/[\r\n]/g, "&lt;br /&gt;");
```

I see in browser
Hi!<br />How are you?

in phpmyadmin I have

```
Hi!&amp;lt;br /&amp;gt;How are you?
```

with

```
sendDataComment.comment = commentForm.find("textarea").val().replace(/\n/g,"<br/>");
```

I see in browser

```
**Hi!<br/>How are you?**
```

in phpmyadmin I have

```
Hi!&lt;br/&gt;How are you?
```

There original is

```
sendDataComment.comment = commentForm.find("textarea").val();
```